# Which configuration do I choose for my laptop?

Tags: performance

I am to purchase a laptop today. I have narrowed down to 2 choices.

- An [Acer](https://www.flipkart.com/acer-nitro-5-core-i7-7th-gen-16-gb-1-tb-hdd-128-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-4-graphics-an515-51-gaming-laptop/p/itmev4sgheh3pvxg?pid=COMEV4SGYG7HM6QP) laptop with 16 GB RAM (expandable to 32 GB) and with GTX 1050 4 GB graphics processor.
- A [Del](https://www.flipkart.com/dell-inspiron-core-i7-7th-gen-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-windows-10-home-4-gb-graphics-7567-gaming-laptop/p/itmeszyxanehpss7?pid=COMESZYXCHKY4Z3C&lid=LSTCOMESZYXCHKY4Z3CA2IR3Q) laptop with 8 GB RAM (expandable to 16GB) but with GTX 1050Ti 4GB graphics processor.

The prices are almost the same. The Acer has a 128GB SSD in addition to a 1TB HDD. But I am willing to compromise on that **IF** 1050Ti with 8 GB RAM will give me substantially good performance compared with 1050 with 16GB RAM

**USAGE**

- Heavy gaming (2-3 hours per day) - GTA V, Witcher 3, Skyrim, etc.
- Mobile application development (1-2 hours per day) - Android Studio

Comment: Better in what ways? What games will you be playing? The more you can give us, the better our answers will be.

Comment: I have made a few minor changes in the question @Cfinley. Hope that works

Comment: You really have to define budget, uses and preferences

Comment: @eddr Price for both is almost the same. I will be choosing **ONLY** from the two. I have specified my use in the question. I do not know if my question is off topic here. I just need some idea about which one of these 2 would be a better choice as one has GTX 1050 with 16GB RAM and the other GTX 1050Ti with 8GB RAM

Comment: @eddr Made some more minor edits.

Comment: The Dell would be a lot faster for gaming then. The Ti variant is around 40% faster on average. Display is pretty lousy, but can be replaced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the Acer.

Reasons.

It has an SSD which improves boot times.
It comes stock with 16GB of RAM, which is the most you should realistically need for gaming.

Also, some applications, including possibly Android Studio, will benefit from the extra RAM and SSD speeds.

With the Acer, you get more bang for the buck without having to upgrade.

Seeing as the two GPUs both have 4GB of VRAM, I would imagine that the significance of performance is negligible, after all, these are not the top end of GPUs.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Both the machines are upgradable to the same extent.

- SSD can be added.
- More RAM can be added.

Now, Acer comes with the higher specs  in ram and SSD. Which extremely reflects your performance.

Now buying is dependent on pricing of the machines. If Acer comes at the same cost of dell or slightly higher or lower then simply choose the Acer blind folded.

Because 8 gig stick and a 128 SSD disk sums around INR 11k in India. Which is really a big amount.

Then comes the brand, If you're not brand conscious, I hope you will pick the right one. :-)